# Buildable libraries cannot import or export from non-buildable libraries (eslint)

Tags: nomachine-nx, nx-workspace

I am getting above error when i import the interface from one of the library:

```
import { DetailsProps } from '@vite/prop-types'; //error
import styles from './header.module.less';

const initailDetails: DetailsProps = {
  name: 'Arif',
  city: 'Chennai',
  pin: 600019,
};
export function Header() {
  return (
    <div className={styles['container']}>
      <h1>Welcome to Header!</h1>
      <ul>
        {Object.values(initailDetails).map((v) => (
          <li key={v}>{v}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Nx report:

```
  Node : 16.13.2
   OS   : darwin arm64
   npm  : 8.1.2
   
   nx : 15.3.3
   @nrwl/angular : Not Found
   @nrwl/cypress : 15.3.3
   @nrwl/detox : Not Found
   @nrwl/devkit : 15.3.3
   @nrwl/esbuild : Not Found
   @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx : 15.3.3
   @nrwl/expo : Not Found
   @nrwl/express : Not Found
   @nrwl/jest : Not Found
   @nrwl/js : 15.3.3
   @nrwl/linter : 15.3.3
   @nrwl/nest : Not Found
   @nrwl/next : Not Found
   @nrwl/node : Not Found
   @nrwl/nx-cloud : Not Found
   @nrwl/nx-plugin : Not Found
   @nrwl/react : 15.3.3
   @nrwl/react-native : Not Found
   @nrwl/rollup : Not Found
   @nrwl/schematics : Not Found
   @nrwl/storybook : Not Found
   @nrwl/web : Not Found
   @nrwl/webpack : Not Found
   @nrwl/workspace : 15.3.3
   typescript : 4.8.4
   ---------------------------------------
   Local workspace plugins:
   ---------------------------------------
   Community plugins:
     @nrwl/vite: 15.3.3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I removed this from my project.json of the library that was buildable (which does not have to be the library that the import stems from, can also be the library the the import goes to):

```
"build": {
  "executor": "@nx/js:tsc",
  "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/libs/shared/dto",
    "main": "libs/shared/dto/src/index.ts",
    "tsConfig": "libs/shared/dto/tsconfig.lib.json",
    "assets": ["libs/shared/dto/*.md"]
  }
},
```

then invalidated caches and the error was gone

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the buildability of a library, you need to determine whether this library should be built or not. If your answer is negative, you can make it non-buildable by opening its `project.json` file and removing the build runner from its list. Note that sometimes this error may arise due to not specifying the scope for a library and its accessibility level. In such cases, add the "tags" field to the project.json file, which is an array consisting of two indices: the first one is "type," and the second one is "scope," defined as follows:

**project.json:**

```
...,
tags:['type:ui', 'scope:library-name'],
...
```